# How to resolve the camera issue in mi phones using xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-camera-intent

I want to use a camera from mi phone and I created a POC by using following link.
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/camera_intent/take_a_picture_and_save_using_camera_app/
but the problem is that when I opened the camera the app closing automatically especially this problem was coming with mi phones and it's working fine with other phones. Can you please suggest what to do. It is very important for my project.

Comment: Share some code which you have tried so we can take a look.

Comment: the same code which I mentioned in the link am trying it as a poc now..